# SCSS - Extend selector that is used in multiple media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

This is one for the SCSS pros. I want to extend a selector within a media query. I'm not "leaving" the scope, the selector and the line where I extend are in the same media query.

However, I use the selector that I want to extend in another media query as well and that gives me an error, when I extend it.

I don't know if I explained it well, but you might get it from my code:

Partial File _tablet.scss

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {

  .font-family {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  body {
    @extend .font-family;
  }

}
```

Partial file _desktop.scss

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .font-family {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  body {
    @extend .font-family;
  }

}
```

This gives me the following error:

You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
From "@extend .font-family" on line 8 of _desktop.scss

I know that you can't extent an outer selector from within @media, but that's not what I'm trying to do here.

When I leave one of the above files out, it works. So somehow SASS thinks that I want to select a selector from the other media query, which I don't. Am I doing something wrong here? How do you extend selectors that are being used in multiple media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try to **inheritance** by extending a parent (placeholder) selector. You can read more in this [**link**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/extending-in-sass-without-mess/#extend-a-selector-as-few-times-as-possible-).

```
  %font-family {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .font-family, body {
    @extend %font-family
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your body declaration outside the media queries, even if the thing it extends only exists within the media queries.

for example, this:

```
body {
  @extend .font-family;
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .font-family {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 888px) {
  .font-family {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}
```

will compile to this:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .font-family, body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 888px) {
  .font-family, body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}
```